# hangman in prolog

Tags: string, prolog

I am a beginner to prolog. How can I convert letters into * (asterisk)?
I know that it is a character codes in prolog to represent strings. The problem is if it is a letter, convert it to " *", if it is a underscore, just keep it.

So how do I know whether it is a underscore or not?

Answer (score 1):

So, the task is to replace letters with asterisks.
At first, you should google [some material](http://obvcode.blogspot.com/2008/11/working-with-strings-in-prolog.html) about strings in prolog. Than it's easy to have something like that

```
string_replace( [], [] ).
string_replace( [H | Tail], StringNew ) :-
    ( not(underscore(H)), asterisk(A), StringNew = [A | StringTail], string_replace( Tail, StringTail) )
    ;
    ( underscore(H), StringNew = [H | StringTail], string_replace( Tail, StringTail) )
    .

letter( X ) :-
    ( X >= 97, X =< 122 )
    ; 
    ( X >=65, X =<90 ).

underscore( 95 ).
asterisk( 42 ).

main :-
    string_replace( "test_string", S1 ),
    writef( "%s", [S1] ), nl,
    string_replace( "another string", S2 ),
    writef( "%s", [S2] ), nl,
    !
    .
```

It works like that

```
?- main.
****_******
**************
true.
```

It don't use any builtins predicates, but it's could be useful to understand how all it really works.

Comment: I think that is much better teach standard ISO usage, and so it's character notation, and idioms implemented for common task (like maplist). Comparison operators ARE builtins.

Comment: i know how to do this now, use  name()

Answer (score 0):

check each character in string:

```
...maplist(convstar, String, Converted), ...

convstar(0'_, 0'_).
convstar(_, 0'*).
```

Another way, using an 'if-then' construct:

```
convstar(X, Y) :-
  (  X == 0'_
  -> Y = 0'_
  ;  Y = 0'*
  ).
```

Comment: Your first way might need a cut to prevent backtracking to succeed in the second clause when it already succeeded in the first one.